# Declare columns of a table with a varchar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

```
DECLARE @newcolumns VARCHAR(2000);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(DateOut, ']', ''), '[', '') DateOut 
    FROM 
        #Columns
)
SELECT 
    @newcolumns = COALESCE(@newcolumns + ',' + '[' + DateOut + '] REAL', 
    '[' + DateOut + '] REAL') 
FROM 
    cte

CREATE TABLE #newtable 
(
     Area NVARCHAR(50),
     EqpType NVARCHAR(50),
     @newcolumns
)
```

I have this code the variable `@newcolumns` returns me something like

```
[dec-1] real, [dec-2] real, [dec-3] real
```

I tried use another variable like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)
SET @sql = '

CREATE TABLE #newtable 
(
     Area NVARCHAR(50),
     EqpType NVARCHAR(50), ' + @newcolumns + ')
INSERT INTO #newtable
SELECT Area,EqpType,'+@listMAX+'
FROM #littletable
PIVOT (MAX(Metric) FOR DateOut IN ('+@list+')) Z
GROUP BY Area,EqpType
ORDER BY AREA' EXEC (@sql)
```

And that works really good, but is there some way to do the same without using another variable? Like `@sql`?

Comment: why would you remove the brackets? `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(DateOut, ']', ''), '[', '') DateOut FROM #Columns` and then add them back?

Comment: You could make this a lot simpler by using select into. then you don't need to jump through all these hoops. Select * into #newtable from #littletable. but this begs the question.....why do you need to have a second copy of your temp table? This really has the appearance of an XY problem.

Comment: @scsimon, one reason I can think of is that some values of `DateOut` may have square brackets and some may not.   Replacing them if they are there makes them uniform, so that when they are added back in, each will only have one set of brackets.

Comment: Hmmm, good thinking @TabAlleman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not.   To use variables for column names, you have to use dynamic sql, which is what you are doing with the `@sql` variable.